# rewrite git history to store repo in a new toplevel directory

Tags: git

How can I rewrite history so commits beneath root dir appear beneath a new sub directory?

```
original: foo/bar.txt
desired: newsubdir/foo/bar.txt
```

I'm trying to split a directory from a repo and import it to another, but conflicts on the root are a problem (see [Splitting a subfolder out into a new repository](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository)

When I filter the subdirectory I want, it becomes root with its README.md and .gitingnore causing many conflicts when I try to port this over to an existing repository as a subdirectory.

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter  foo --
result:  history of /foo stored as /
```

So, I'd like to find a way of:

- filter all commit data outside of /foo so I'm left with only /foo in my source repo
- filter-branch with subdirectory filter and new prefix

Has anyone achieve this such that the new repo has zero history outside of the new dir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pruning, an index filter can be used to transform into a new subdirectory

see [git documentation: git-filter-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) for this example

To move the whole tree into a subdirectory, or remove it from there:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
    'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&newsubdir/-" |
        GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new \
            git update-index --index-info &&
     mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD
```

FYI, some sed exes (notably macOS) won't use \t as tab and one can use a pasted tab char

Comment: You can also/instead do one single pass of `git filter-branch` with an index filter that removes all things *not* named `foo/`, although this is a bit trickier to write.

Comment: @torek thanks, transforming the repo from everything to subdir as /foo is exactly what I want because then, I can pull that into an existing repo in a specific spot with zero risk of conflicts.

Comment: In that case, consider either: `git ls-files -z | something-that-reads-and-removes` or using a similar `sed` as the one above, but using `sed -n -e '/\tfoo\//p'` to keep the files whose name starts with `foo/`.